# Connected Websocket in Delphi, but no data

Tags: delphi, websocket, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am making first steps with websockets in a Delphi program, connected to an industrial device.

The device can be connected to using `ws://` protocol, and will every second return a 500+/- byte JSON string. This is what I would like to listen to and display in a GUI. I will not have any HTML / JS frontend for this.

I have used the [library IdWebsocketSimpleClient](https://github.com/adaloveless/commonx/blob/master/IdWebsocketSimpleClient.pas), with Delphi 10.4 Community Edition.

I have the following code. It will connect just fine, I get the message about connection. But there is never any data returned. I would have thought that `DataEvent` would trigger if any is received.

So what am I missing in order to receive something ? Making feet wet here with D10 for the first time.

I do have F.Piettes / OverByte components installed as well.

```pascal
unit unitDemoTestWS;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  webSocketClientUnit, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    mmo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure lSWC1DataEvent(Sender: TObject; const Text: string);
    procedure onmyconnected(Sender: Tobject);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    lSWC:TIdSimpleWebSocketClient;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tform1.lSWC1DataEvent(Sender: TObject; const Text: string);
begin
  mmo1.Lines.Add(text);
end;

procedure TForm1.onmyconnected(Sender: Tobject);
begin
   mmo1.lines.add ('We are connected');
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    try
      lSWC.Host := '192.168.0.134';
      lswc.Port := 55902;
      lSWC.Connect;
    except
      mmo1.lines.add('Refused Connect!');
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
      try
        lSWC := TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Create(self);
        lSWC.onDataEvent := lSWC1DataEvent;
        lswc.OnConnected := onmyconnected;
        mmo1.Clear;
        lSWC.AutoCreateHandler := False;

      finally
      end;
  end;
end.
```

The following Python code works and continously prints the received data - but I would like to display parts of the data using Delphi controls.

```py
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://192.168.0.134:55902")

while (True):     
  r =  ws.recv()
  print (r)
  
ws.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not connecting the `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient` to the server correctly.

`TIdSimpleWebSocketClient` derives from `TIdTCPClient`, which has a public parameter-less `Connect()` method.  You are calling the `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` method directly, which will simply open the TCP connection and do nothing else.  That is why you are not receiving any data.

`TIdSimpleWebSocketClient` has its own `Connect()` method (declared as `overload` but it [should have been `reintroduce` instead](https://github.com/adaloveless/commonx/issues/11)), which takes a WebSocket URL as an input parameter:

```pascal
procedure Connect(pURL:String);overload;
```

That is the method you need to call instead, eg:

```pascal
{lSWC.Host := '192.168.0.134';
lswc.Port := 55902;
lSWC.Connect;}
lSWC.Connect('ws://192.168.0.134:55902');
```

Internally, `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Connect()` parses the URL to setup the `Host` and `Port` properties, and then connects to the server, but it also does several other things, too:

- setup the `IOHandler` to enable TLS if accessing a secure WSS url and `AutoCreateHandler` is true.
- performs the WebSocket handshake.
- starts a worker thread to process incoming data.
- starts a worker thread to handle WebSocket heartbeats.

This use of `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Connect()` is even demonstrated in a code example located at the very top of `IdWebsocketSimpleClient.pas`:

```pascal
{
Sample code:
//var lSWC:TIdSimpleWebSocketClient;
...
begin
  lSWC := TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.Create(self);
  lSWC.onDataEvent           := self.lSWC1DataEvent;  //TSWSCDataEvent
  lSWC.AutoCreateHandler := false; //you can set this as true in the majority of Websockets with ssl
  if not lSWC.AutoCreateHandler then
  begin
    if lSWC.IOHandler=nil then
      lSWC.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lSWC);
    (lSWC.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.Mode := TIdSSLMode.sslmClient;
    (lSWC.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1, TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_1, TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_2];
  end;
  lSWC.Connect('wss://echo.websocket.org');
  lSWC.writeText('!!It worked!!');
end;
}
```

---

That being said, there is another issue with your code.  The `TIdSimpleWebSocketClient.onDataEvent` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread, so your handler must synchronize with the main UI thread when updating your Memo, eg:

```pascal
procedure Tform1.lSWC1DataEvent(Sender: TObject; const Text: string);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, // or TThread.Queue()
    procedure
    begin
      mmo1.Lines.Add(text);
    end
  );
end;
```